# How can I load my own picture in OpenAI Gym?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, pyglet, openai-gym

I tried to load my own picture, which is in png version into an application in OpenAI Gym. But the result is all black. 
The loading sentence is :

```
    fname = path.join("filename.jpg")
    self.img = rendering.Image(fname, 2., 2.)
    self.imgtrans = rendering.Transform()
    self.img.add_attr(self.imgtrans)
    self.viewer.add_onetime(self.img)
```

I have found that the loading code behind it is:

```
class Image(Geom):
    def __init__(self, fname, width, height):
        Geom.__init__(self)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        img = pyglet.image.load(fname)
        self.img = img
        self.flip = False
    def render1(self):
        self.img.blit(-self.width/2, -self.height/2, width=self.width, height=self.height)
```

Comment: What's `rendering` here?

Comment: It is a function in gym

Comment: It feels like pyglet hasn't been properly set up. Or an appropriate view/projection hasn't been set up. In order to diagnose we'd need a minimal working example. Or the relevant code where initialization has been done.